# Spring reference a property from a property bean

Tags: java, spring, dependency-properties

I have created a spring configuration file that works well.

My next step was to separate user configuration properties from system properties.

I have decided to create additional xml file with beans that will be configured by the user.

I had problem to create few such logical beans encapsulating properties that will be used by real class beans:

I have found over the net an option to reference proprieties in such way:

UserConf.xml

```
<bean id="numberGuess" class="x...">
    <property name="randomNumber" value="5"/>

    <!-- other properties -->
</bean>
```

SystemConf.xml

```
<import resource="UserConf.xml" />

<bean id="shapeGuess" class="y...">
    <property name="initialShapeSeed" value="#{ numberGuess.randomNumber }"/>

    <!-- other properties -->
</bean>
```

But my problem is that i need `x...` class to be something logical that shouldn't be initialized at all, and i don't want it to disclose any info of the class hierarchy of the system since it should be only in use configuration xml file.

**Solution1** is to create a Java object representing this proprieties:

```
public class MyProps(...)
```

and add a bean parent in the spring system configuration:

```
<bean id="MyProps" class="path to MyProps"/>
```

in the user side change the previous bean to be:

```
<bean id="numberGuess" parent="MyProps">
    <property name="randomNumber" value="5"/>

    <!-- other properties -->
</bean>
```

**Solution2** is to use flat configuration file just like Database.props, and load it using factory.

**Solution3** is to use Spring Property Placeholder configuration to load properties from XML properties file (e.g. [example](http://rvsoni.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/spring-property-placeholder-configuration-to-load-properties-from-xml-properties-file/)), but here i simply don't know how to get a more complex nested structure of properties (properties need to be separated by different logical names, e.g. minNumber will be defined both under xAlgo and y algo).

I don't like to create new Java class only to deal with this problem or to move my user configuration to a flat props file (i need the xml structure), is their any other solution??

Comment: Where will the properties in "x" class be used?

Comment: Sorry I'm unclear why you can't just use properties files?

Comment: @cowls: in different beans in the SystemConf file,

Comment: @Tom McIntyre: I gave only a simple example for a property , part of my properties and beans could be and will be with complex XML structure

Comment: @cowls:I have added solution 3 that is preferable if i will be able to separate the properties to different logical parts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer my own question, since it looks as the best solution for me (and much more simplistic than was suggested)

I will use PropertiesFactoryBean to do the work for me:

e.g.

UserConf.xml

```
<bean id="numberGuess" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="properties">
    <props>
        <prop key="randomNumber">3</prop>

    <!-- other properties -->
</bean>
```

SystemConf.xml

```
<import resource="UserConf.xml" />

<bean id="shapeGuess" class="y...">
    <property name="initialShapeSeed" value="#{ numberGuess.randomNumber }"/>

    <!-- other properties -->
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

First if you don't know about the [property place holder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factory-postprocessors) you should take a look at that. Also `@Value("${some.property:defaultvalue}")` is something you should look at.

Second the word *configuration* is ambiguous in Spring. Spring uses this word but they mean developer configuration not user configuration. Despite what people say or think Spring is not a configuration engine.

I'm not sure what your trying to do but you should be aware that your configuration will not be adjusted at runtime which is frequently needed for something like "*user*" configuration. So most people write their own configuration layer.

Another thing you should take a look at is not using the XML configuration and instead use [Java Configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java) which will give you way more flexibility.

Comment: I am familiar with the configuration aspect of Spring, most of the links on web are for using props flat file, i need and example how property place holder uses complex xml properties, similar to this link http://rvsoni.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/spring-property-placeholder-configuration-to-load-properties-from-xml-properties-file/, but with logically separated properties chunks , can you supply an example or a link?

Comment: When configuration gets complicated (ie nesting) I use Jackson or JAXB to deserialize a config file to a data POJO like your MyProps. Where the JSON or XML file is configured as a Property (System property or environment... etc).

Comment: no other way to solve it?, isn't there a default bean that can be defined in XML , and you may reference to its inner nested property without using placeholders?

Comment: Well yes you could do an `<import...` based off a property but you will still need another bean like `MyProps`. Its ok to have another object as it provides a layer of indirection (the hallmark of software design).

Comment: I have found a solution that seems to be more simplistic, so i attached an answer to my post, Thanks for your help